# How to smooth a logarithmic spectrogram line, less on low values more on high values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft

I generate spectrum analysis plots using `matplotlib`. The plot contains minimum, maximum and average value over time range. One random plot looks like this:

[image]

The FFT data is extensive, with very low to high frequencies. The X-Axis of the plot is logarithmic to cover a wide frequency range.

Now I would like to smooth the curve slightly over the whole frequency range, *but* less on the lower frequencies and more on the higher ones.

This example uses the following code to smooth the curve:

```
mean_data = signal.savgol_filter(data.mean(axis=1), 11, 3)
max_data = signal.savgol_filter(data.max(axis=1), 11, 3)
min_data = signal.savgol_filter(data.min(axis=1), 11, 3)
```

The value `11` is great for the frequencies 0-100Hz, but with increasing frequencies, there are more data points and a larger window would be required for better smoothing.

**How can I smooth a spectrum, less on low values and more on the higher ones?**

More specific questions?

- Is there a function with an logarithmic/increasing window size?
- Is there a best practice how to smooth this kind of spectrogram curves?

Comment: Did you try taking the log of your curve, then filtering and then taking exp again?

Comment: @JohanC The curve is the result of an FFT, which is linear. With the logarithmic display, there are more data points at higher frequencies compressed to smaller space. To get a smooth curve for the higher frequencies, a filter needs to use a larger window there.